# SwiftUI: Timer.publish not working on Lock Screen widget iOS 16

Tags: swiftui, ios16, lockscreenwidget

I am implementing timer on lock screen widget using Timer.publish and .onReceive on Text. But the timer is not firing.                                                                               let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

I have a Text() in ZStack which I want to update.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Widgets are static, your app sends an encoding of the View structs to the lock screen so none of the actions work. However, there are ways to request a refresh, see [Keeping a Widget Up To Date | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/keeping-a-widget-up-to-date)